# Host .svc file on ASP.NET Development Server

Tags: wcf

Is it possible to host .svc file on ASP.NET Development Server? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. 
If your project type is regular library project then one way is to create a website project and copy the svc file + corresponding service dll's to the bin folder for that project.

Then, when you run the solution (F5), you will find that the website is hosted in cassini (asp.net development server)

The only catch is that the virtual port is different everytime you run the solution.
However, you can specify the project to run on a specific virtual port as well.

[Refer this link on how you can do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322384/vs-2008-debugger-how-does-it-decide-what-cassini-port-to-run-a-web-service-under)